# Best method for creating absolute path in PHP? (See 3 methods listed inside)

Tags: php, path

I can create paths with no problem, but I want to know which of these 3 methods is the most rock solid and reliable and will work on the most servers.

Right now I am using method 1 in my script and some users are having path issues. I just want the method that will work on any version of php and almost any server config.

```
1.  <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>

2.  <?php echo getcwd(); ?>

3.  <?php echo dirname(__FILE__); ?>
```

Thank you so much for any expertise you can provide about this!

Comment: They will all work, but they may produce different results, as they do different things. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What are the "path issues" they are having?

Comment: Basically I am trying to point to a file that is at a fixed location and I want the URL to valid no matter where it is called from.  For example: "/home/sitecom/public_html/myfile.php"

So I want to get the rootpath to the file which is something like: "/home/sitecom/public_html"

Using method 1 seems to do the trick most of the time, but for a few users its not working as expected.

Comment: The path issue is simply that its not working.  When I view the code its not generating the path at all, its just blank and only shows the file name,

Comment: Option 1 won't work if you use a shared hosting service.

Answer (score 9):

`dirname(__FILE__)` will always work, regardless of platform or webserver.  DOCUMENT_ROOT may work differently between server configurations (Apache vs IIS vs Lighttpd vs nginex).  cwd shows the selected working directory which may or may not be correct (you can change it in the script).  So I'd suggest `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: +1 The first thing I add to a new project is  `define('ROOT',realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/');`

Answer (score 2):

- $_SERVER array <strike>holds user data and therefore can't be trusted</strike> is dependent on the platform (webserver).
- The current working directory may depend on the entry point of the request. Consider this example (CLI):

  ```
  cd ~/mypath/mypath2
  php myscript.php
  cd ~/mypath
  php mypath/myscript.php
  ```
- IMHO the securest solution is to use `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` (since PHP 5.3) as the file path will always be the same (relative to your projects structure).

Comment: OK, it seems the consensus is that dirname(__FILE__) is th way to go.  Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: It's not correct to say that $_SERVER is all user generated. A lot of it is from the server side, not the client (e.g. the 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' value can be trusted).

Comment: you're right on this for the DOCUMENT_ROOT entry (and others of course). but still there are variables in the $_SERVER array that can be spoofed by the client/user. and in the context of the application that data is foreign and should not be trusted blindly.