# Why do my php includes return, "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in..."

Tags: php, include

I'm using simple include files for common elements on a mostly static website.  I do so like this

```
<?php include('/inc/header.php'); ?>
```

But this doesn't work unless i remove the leading slash, and then it only works on pages in the root directory.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'/' means the real server root directory.

If you need web document root use :

```
 include("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/inc/header.php");
```

Comment: I went a step further and did this: 
set_include_path("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/inc");
so that I could call all the includes using just the file name like this:
include('filename.php');

Comment: For portability sake, I wouldn't recommend using any of the `$_SERVER` paths...  I recommend [`dirname(__FILE__);`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893088/best-method-for-creating-absolute-path-in-php-see-3-methods-listed-inside/2893104#2893104) since it will always work 100% of the time...

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew Nice reference. Now if you want to make it a universal one, then mentioning common patterns like utilizing `DOCUMENT_ROOT` or a custom app root constant would make sense.

Comment: @mario thanks for the suggestion. At which point in the answer do you suggest I add it ?

Answer (score 3):

`/...` is an absolute path on unix systems. To specify a relative path use `./...`. That will be relative to the called file's directory.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

You have an absolute path - i.e. starts with `/`. So it is looking in your server root.

Without the slash it is a relative path and will look relative to the PHP file's path.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

**Use this solution**

I also facing same problem 
Warning: include(/test/assets/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/test/assets/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear')

But I solve them after searching it on google in 2 dyas.

**Solution:**
you have to define your path then use include function as blow:

define (DOC_ROOT_PATH, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');

you can use any directory structure after that.

Answer (score 0):

add "."before path like that :

`<?php include('./inc/header.php'); ?>`

The path meanings:

- `/` is the root of the current drive.
- `./` is the current directory (that what you want).
- `../` is the parent of the current directory.