# Including files using relative paths with PHP?

Tags: php

When developing my website I called all the includes in my php files by calling one single file called includes.

The code of this file looked somethig like this: (I adapted it from a Lynda tutorial)

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :
    define('SITE_ROOT', 'C:'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'ArmyCreator');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');
defined('PUB_PATH') ? null : define('PUB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'public');


// load config file first
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."helper".DS.'config.php');
```

Now since I am deploying my webiste I can't figure out how to declare the SITE_ROOt to make it work properly?

**EDIT**

Is it normal for  code like this: `require_once("../../includes/helper/initialize.php");` to not work anymore once I deploy to the website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include the files relative to includes.php's directory by doing:

```
<?
$basePath = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once($basePath . "relative/path/from/basePath"); // replace the string with your real relative path
```

Comment: unfortunately IDE don't like variables in paths :(

Comment: Or `__DIR__`, since PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: I'm not using 5.3 yet. @dorkitude. I used this but I can't see if it works because i realized that all the formulations that I made with require_once("../../includes/helper/initialize.php"); don't work either.

Comment: You should add a `$basePath` like in my example, rather than doing the relative paths

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions here:

1. You're going to want `SITE_ROOT` to be absolute path of the directory your files are located in. For example, in the above code, this directory is `C:\wamp\www\ArmyCreator`. You can define this manually if you know the directory, or dynamically by using the predefined `__DIR__` constant (PHP 5.3+), or `dirname(__FILE__)` if you're not on 5.3 yet.
2. Including a bunch of files all at once in generally considered bad practice, and autoloading should be used instead. This will give you better performance as well as a well-defined directory layout and naming scheme, leading to better code. To do this, you can use the [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't abuse ternary syntax like that.  Instead of `defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`, you can use the `OR` operator (which will short-circuit on a boolean true result):

```
defined('DS') OR define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Secondly, if this is inside of a bootstrap file that you know the position of, simply use `dirname(__FILE__)`:

```
defined('SITE_ROOT') OR define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Otherwise, if you know the relative position of the root, you can use multiple `dirname` calls.  So if it's the parent directory of the present one:

```
defined('SITE_ROOT') OR define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Don't use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or `cwd()` or hardcode your path.  Always use `dirname(__FILE__)` to determine the absolute path.  For more info on why, see [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893088/best-method-for-creating-absolute-path-in-php-see-3-methods-listed-inside/2893104#2893104)

Comment: Even cleaner than `or` would be `if (!defined('...')) { define('...') }`

Comment: Quite true @mfonda, but there's a line between verbosity and clutter.  Having a whole bunch of `if` statements (taking between 2 and 3 lines each, since I don't know of a single coding standard that allows inline-if statements) is more clutter than it may be worth...  But to each their own...

Answer (score 0):

First off: I'd drop the DS, it's BS (ehe). Windows support both `C:/wamp/www` and `C:\wamp\www` :-) Even `C:\wamp\www/project` is fine.

If `includes.php` is located in, say `lib/includes.php` (relative to your project root), then do this:

```
define('SITE_ROOT', realpath('../'));
```

That will dynamically set `SITE_ROOT`.

Comment: The `DS` is not BS.  Sure, windows supports both path syntaxes, but it's ambiguous and will not match the result of `realpath()`.  I do consider it to be very bad practice to blindly use `/` on windows systems.  But that's just my $0.02...