# how do I redirect my php login to a higher folder?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication, member

I have a script in website.com/login/, it contains all the files and forms need to proccess user authentication and contains the forms as well. I have the main login form on my main index, website.com/index.php. I have successfully directed the form to post /login/login-exec.php, but once the script has run it redirects to /login/login-success.php, not website.com/index.php?od=logsucc. How would i go about telling the login-exec.php to redirect to the main folder of the website instead of /login/?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737609/including-files-using-relative-paths-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
header( 'Location: /index.php?od=logsucc' );
```

the leading `/` says go back to the site root directory.

Comment: I'm gonna give that a try, i'll let ya know if it worked in a few moments.

Comment: on my domain it works aka mydomain.com/index.php

Comment: but on the server level hostingsite.com/~user/index.php its telling me this: HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: index.php

Comment: Ok try this  header( 'Location: ../index.php?od=logsucc' );  That says go back one level and look for index.php

Comment: it actually reroutes to hostingsite.com/index.php instead of.

Comment: hostingsite.com/~user/

Comment: I thought it was probably you @JayBlanchard :) Thanks :) :)