# PHP sees '/' as '/' instead of '/var/www/html' even though document root is set

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permissions

Should I be using .htaccess or is this something in the httpd.conf file? or is this something in php.ini?

I've set my document root in httpd.conf to /var/www/html, and the site is working properly.

Problem is that when I use include("/file"); it looks at the root of my server rather than the root of my website.

Thanks! I'm still a little bit new to server administration. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: What does [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) output?

Comment: As far as I know, the DocRoot is just for apache.  PHP will reference files from your system root.  `define` some globals you can use in your specific PHP application that define to roots to the site.

Comment: getcwd() outputs /var/www/html, as would be expected I guess... I'll look in php.ini and see if i can set this globally

Comment: You really shouldn't set it in your php.ini.  the ini should define system wide settings.  You don't want to define site/application specific settings in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best method for creating absolute path in PHP? (See 3 methods listed inside)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893088/best-method-for-creating-absolute-path-in-php-see-3-methods-listed-inside)

Comment: Thanks everybody! Answered my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding current directory (`.`) to your [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path): "*Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include() will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing*."

EDIT:

ah, I think the problem is that you're starting your path with `/` which will translate to the root of the filesystem, not the root of the webserver.
If you want to include something from the root of your project, define a constant in the index.php:

```
define('SERVER_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then use it like this:

```
include(SERVER_ROOT . '/file.php');
```

Comment: I guess I am hoping to define the server root in a config file, or alias it somehow in .htaccess, is this even possible? Or am I locked in to using this workaround?

Comment: I agree. You definitely should be using something like `dirname(__FILE__)` as a starting point. `__FILE__` will specify the path of the file that it is executed in.

Comment: @Jonathan Coe, you can define this variable whereever you want. E.g. if your config file is in the folder /cfg (relative to the project's root), then `define('SERVER_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));` in that file. I prefer to define this directly in the main file and use it to include/require my libraries.

Comment: Why not use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead? that comes directly from Apache. A script's location in the file system may have absolutely nothing to do with where it appears in a site's URL-side tree, especially if you're using Aliases and mod_rewrite .

Comment: Marc, that depends if your document_root is also the root of your application. For example my structure is DOCUMENT_ROOT/projects/project_name. I'd have to use `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . PROJECT_PATH . '/file.php');` so why not save the whole thing in it's own constant.