# Define absolute path for files

Tags: php

I have the following include files..

```
require_once ("config.php");
require_once ("functions.php");
require_once ("session.php");
```

I want to define absolute paths for my include files. I have tried with the following code and no luck..

can you please help to define an appropriate absolute path, so that require_once as expected.

```
    defined('DS') ? null : define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null: define('SITE_ROOT',DS.'PHP_Files'. DS . 'phpsandbox'. DS.'my_mat'. DS.'my_test');
    defined('LIB_PATH')?null:define('LIB_PATH',SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");
    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."functions.php");
    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."session.php");
```

These 3 include files in my system are stored in J:\PHP_Files\phpsandbox\my_mat\my_test\includes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best method for creating absolute path in PHP? (See 3 methods listed inside)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893088/best-method-for-creating-absolute-path-in-php-see-3-methods-listed-inside)

Comment: Also, don't abuse the ternary operator like that.  If you must do short syntax, use `OR` instead: `defined('DS') OR define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

Comment: I am new to php. so it is little difficult for me to understand what you have meant. It would be great if you can explain in detail.I am checking if the constant DS is defined or not. If it is not defined, i am defining it..If there is anything wrong it, I would be happy to learn

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I think what you are looking for is the actual system file path. To get that you can echo

```
dirname( __FILE__ );
```

You can do this in any file that you want and it will display the system file path relative to your file. For me it's something like this:

```
/home2/myusername/public_html/project_name/includes/config.php
```

so if you are interested in the "project_name" folder you should have something like this:

```
defined("SITE_ROOT") ? null : define("SITE_ROOT", DS . "home2" . DS . "myusername" . DS . "public_html" . DS . "project_name" );
```

Then if you are looking for the "includes" folder which will be your library you should have something like this:

```
defined("LIB_PATH")  ? null : define("LIB_PATH", SITE_ROOT . DS . "includes" );
```

Hope this helps. I had the exact same problem and this worked for me.

Cheers, Mihai Popa

Answer (score 0):

You need [realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function. Also, you can get all files included by [get_included_files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) that returns array of absolute paths of files you've included at the moment function's got called.

```
defined('DS') or define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$disk_label = '';
if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT') {
    if (FALSE !== ($pos = strpos(__FILE__, ':'))) {
        $disk_label = substr(__FILE__, 0,$pos+1);
    }
}
defined('SITE_ROOT') or define('SITE_ROOT', $disk_label.DS.'PHP_Files'. DS . 'phpsandbox'. DS.'my_mat'. DS.'my_test');
defined('LIB_PATH') or define('LIB_PATH',SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."functions.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."session.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including your LIB_PATH in your include path.

```
set_include_path(LIB_PATH . DS . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DS."config.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DS."functions.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DS."session.php");
```

check it out , i think it's good